# How to retrieve excited state molecular orbital coefficients in Gaussian?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory, td-dft

Currently I am doing TD-DFT calculations in Gaussian and want to calculate transition dipole moment for $S_1$ transition manually. However, I do not manage to retrieve molecular orbital coefficients for the excited states in Gaussian, just the ground state with *population* keyword and a few hours of search through the Internet hasn't helped to move forward. Is it possible to do that and if it is possible, how to achieve that? And just to make sure that I understand the output corrently: the molecular orbital coefficients are given in their casual forms (like $c_1, c_2, etc.$), not a square modulus of them?

Thanks in advance for your help!